# Help with wiring smart dimmer where 4 switches control ceiling lights

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch, smart-switch

I currently have 4 traditional switches (1 dimmer, 3 remote) control ceiling lights in a hallway, using  A - D to represent junction boxes as follows:

- A: 3 way switch
- A -> B: 3 wire romex
- B: 4 way switch
- B -> C: 3 wire romex
- C: 4 way switch + power line from panel (2 wire romex)
- C -> D: 3 wire romex
- D: 3 way (dimmer) + light line (2 wire romex)

I want to change them to smart switches. I bought 1 Leviton DZ6HD Zwave Dimmer, and 3 matching dimmer remote DD00R-DLZ. But I don't know how to wire them, the manual diagram is for the case that the power line goes into one of the ending 3 way switch, but mine goes into the middle 4 way switch (C).

What's the correct wiring for my case?

Link to the manual:

- Dimmer (DZ6HD): https://www.leviton.com/fr/docs/DI-000-DZ6HD-02A-W.pdf
- Remote (DD00R-DLZ): https://www.leviton.com/es/docs/PK-A3123-10-00-2A.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The power and neutral go to *all* the smart switches.

The master must be at the box which has the branch to the light.

I am not at all sure that the Leviton supports multiple remotes. But if it does,  you'll need to allocate all the /3 wires as follows:

- Black = always-hot
- White = neutral
- Red = Yellow/Red data line